# Cannot Clear Search Results when entering new search

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im developing a web app that searches lyrics using Music Match Api but im having trouble clearing the div that produces the results when im doing another search. can someone please help me

heres the script

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var results = '';

    $('#submitButton').on('click',function(){

    clearResults(); 
    //get the artist name and tghe track name
    var artistName = $('#searchArtistName').val();
    var songName = $('#searchTrackName').val();
    makeRequest(artistName,songName);
    e.preventDefault();

    });

    function makeRequest(artistName,songName){



    $.ajax({


    url:"https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/matcher.lyrics.get?q_track="+artistName+"&q_artist="+songName+"&apikey=e87bc35119a5893655c3d0e2c3a4f40b",
    type:'Get',
    dataType:'json'

    }).done(function(response){

    //get the response and then append it to the card
    var message = response.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body;

    console.log(response);


    results += `

    <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="card card-custom bg-white border-white z-depth-5" id = "myCard">
    <div class="card-body" style="overflow-y: auto">
    <i class = "fa fa-book fa-2x text-center"></i>
    <h6 class="card-title" style = "font-size:22px;font-family:Comic Sans MS">Album <br>${message}</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer" style="background: inherit; border-color: inherit;">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
     `;

    $('#shower').html(results);

    });

    }

    function clearResults(){

        $("#shower").html('');

    }

    });
```

heres a snippet of the html file which has two input fields one for artist name and the other for the song name and a button for submission

```
<div class = "container">
           <h4>Search to view lyrics</h4>
            <input type = "text" id = "searchArtistName" style="margin-top: 20px;" class = "form-control" placeholder="Enter Artist Name">
            <input type = "text" id = "searchTrackName" style="margin-top: 20px;" class = "form-control" placeholder="Enter Track Name">
            <br>
            <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-info btn-lg" id = "submitButton">Search</button>
      </div>
    <div class = "container">
          <div id = "shower" class = "row"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you put the result you're looking to achieve ? It will be easier to help you

Comment: im trying to get the song lyrics based on a search of the artist name and the track name. Its showing the result but if i do another search instead of clearing the old results it displays both the old and the new results

Answer (score 1):

It's appending the results because you use result+= instead of result =

Correction :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var results = '';

    $('#submitButton').on('click',function(){
    //get the artist name and tghe track name
    e.preventDefault();
    var artistName = $('#searchArtistName').val();
    var songName = $('#searchTrackName').val();
    makeRequest(artistName,songName);


    });

    function makeRequest(artistName,songName){



    $.ajax({


    url:"https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/matcher.lyrics.get?q_track="+artistName+"&q_artist="+songName+"&apikey=e87bc35119a5893655c3d0e2c3a4f40b",
    type:'Get',
    dataType:'json'

    }).done(function(response){

    //get the response and then append it to the card
    var message = response.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body;

    console.log(response);


    results = `

    <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="card card-custom bg-white border-white z-depth-5" id = "myCard">
    <div class="card-body" style="overflow-y: auto">
    <i class = "fa fa-book fa-2x text-center"></i>
    <h6 class="card-title" style = "font-size:22px;font-family:Comic Sans MS">Album <br>${message}</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer" style="background: inherit; border-color: inherit;">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
     `;

    $('#shower').html(results);

    });

    }


    });
```

I got ride of clearResults as it should not be needed anymore.

Comment: wow thanks a lot that was helpful. i was failing to see my error but you cleared that up.

Comment: if this is the correct answer give him, what he deserve. kindly mark him as correct or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

the following code may help you

```
function clearResults(){

        $("#shower").children().remove();

    }
```